# How to achieve circular flow of scrolling in ngx-carousel in angular4?

Tags: angular

Iam working on angular4 project.Here I have a need of displaying multiple items in a slide in a carousel.For that one I have used ngx-carousel.It works fine but on completion of elements in the looping array,the slider scroll back again violating the circular flow.How can I implement the ngx-carousel to slide to first element without roll-back again(continuous flow)?

Answer (score 1):

it is [yet to be implemented](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngx-carousel/issues/87), according to the github issues of ngx-carousel.

If you are looking for alternative solutions, I suggest [Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). It even has the circular flow you aim for.

Comment: Any other solution for displaying 3 items per slide in a carousel in angular4?

Comment: I need a carousel using ngFor

Comment: you can use it with that.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Answer (score 1):

This feature is added in the latest release of ngx.
Add-

`<carousel [noWrap]="false">
"Your code"
</carousel>`

to get the the continuous flow while clicking on next or previous button.